# Is there a method or an equation to generate coordinates based on relative distances? (Spanning Tree)

Tags: python, math, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

I have a list of point names, and their relative distance from each other (Euclidean distance). Is it possible to plot their coordinates on a 2-D plane where I can set the origin point to be the minimum sum of distances between all other points?

example for an input of 3 points (A,B,C):

```
list = {'AB':'0.15', 'AC':'0.61', 'BC':'0.24'}
```

Desired output:

```
#B is identified as origin so its coordinates is set to (0,0)    
{'A':(x1,y1), 'B':(0,0), 'C':(x2,y2)}
```

I am only trying to plot their Euclidean distance so then I could draw an accurate spanning tree. the input will be much more than 3.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the origin point to be the minimum sum of distances between all other points" (in your question).

Comment: You will need to set at least two points to get a fixed set of positions.  Imagine the triangle ABC anchored on its B point, it can rotate an infinite number of ways around that point so coordinates of A and C cannot be determined.  Is the "minimum sum distances" (whateve that is) meant to solve this ambiguity and if so, how ?

Comment: Yes such a method exists, and no it's not simple when you get to more than 3 points - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration